# Date & time app doesn't start

Tags: java, android, datetime

I made an app where you can click on a button and the it should show the current date and time in an `EditText` field. The problem is that the app crashes when starting..Can  someone help me?

```
package de.example.datumzeit;
```

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
EditText etdate, ettime;
String mytime, mydate;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button datum_einfügen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btngo);
    etdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etdate);
    ettime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ettime);
    datum_einfügen.setOnClickListener(this);

    // time
    mytime = java.text.DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

    // date
    mydate =java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view){
    etdate.setText(mydate); 
    ettime.setText(mytime);
}
```

}

```
}
```

**LogCat:**

```
03-25 10:30:38.298: E/AndroidRuntime(25676): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

03-25 10:30:38.298: E/AndroidRuntime(25676): Process: de.example.datum_zeit, PID: 25676

03-25 10:30:38.298: E/AndroidRuntime(25676): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{de.example.datum_zeit/de.example.datum_zeit.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

03-25 10:30:38.298: E/AndroidRuntime(25676):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)

03-25 10:30:38.298: E/AndroidRuntime(25676):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)

03-25 10:30:38.298: E/AndroidRuntime(25676):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)

03-25 10:30:38.298: E/AndroidRuntime(25676):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)

03-25 10:30:38.298: E/AndroidRuntime(25676):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

03-25 10:30:38.298: E/AndroidRuntime(25676):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)

03-25 10:30:38.298: E/AndroidRuntime(25676):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)

03-25 10:30:38.298: E/AndroidRuntime(25676):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

03-25 10:30:38.298: E/AndroidRuntime(25676):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

03-25 10:30:38.298: E/AndroidRuntime(25676):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)

03-25 10:30:38.298: E/AndroidRuntime(25676):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)

03-25 10:30:38.298: E/AndroidRuntime(25676):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

03-25 10:30:38.298: E/AndroidRuntime(25676): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

03-25 10:30:38.298: E/AndroidRuntime(25676):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1965)

03-25 10:30:38.298: E/AndroidRuntime(25676):    at de.example.datum_zeit.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:26)

03-25 10:30:38.298: E/AndroidRuntime(25676):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)

03-25 10:30:38.298: E/AndroidRuntime(25676):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)

03-25 10:30:38.298: E/AndroidRuntime(25676):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)

03-25 10:30:38.298: E/AndroidRuntime(25676):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2222)

03-25 10:30:38.298: E/AndroidRuntime(25676):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: You need to bring the stack trace here too, otherwise we can't help you

Comment: Move all your UI initialization code into the `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
EditText etdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etdate);
EditText ettime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ettime);
```

is outside of any method.

You need to initialize after setting the content of the layout to the activity

```
EditText etdate;
EditText ettime;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
etdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etdate);
ettime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ettime);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
package de.example.datumzeit;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText etdate, ettime;
    String mytime, mydate;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button datum_einfügen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btngo);
        datum_einfügen.setOnClickListener(this);
        etdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etdate);
        ettime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ettime);
        // time
        mytime = java.text.DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        // date
        mydate =java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        etdate.setText(mydate); 
        ettime.setText(mytime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First i give you a suggestion to go through the document of Number Formatter
May the following one can help you.

```
public static final SimpleDateFormat MMM_DD_YYYY_HH_MM_12_HOURS  = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a");
public static final SimpleDateFormat DD_MM_YYYY_HH_MM_12_HOURS  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");
```

create an instance for this.

Answer (score 0):

you should move

```
EditText etdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etdate);
EditText ettime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ettime);
```

in onCreate() method. Also make EditText variable global.

```
 EditText etdate ,ettime
```

and in onCreate() method

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 Button datum_einfügen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btngo);
 etdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etdate);
 ettime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ettime);
 datum_einfügen.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

***UPDATE:***

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view){


 if(view.getId()==R.id.btngo)
 mytime = java.text.DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

// date
 mydate =java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
 etdate.setText(mydate); 
 ettime.setText(mytime);
}
}
```

And remove this

```
 mytime = java.text.DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

// date
mydate =java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

from onCreate() method.

Comment: I did this, but it still doesn't work. And the Logcat is still the same

Comment: thanks for your help but it doesn't work. It still chrashes when starting.

Comment: Now check again answer.

Comment: it works! it was a mistake in the activity_main :S
THANKS A LOT!

Answer (score -1):

The initialization  of `etdate` and `ettime` should be in a method, like `onCreate`.